# Django store attachment in Data Lake

Tags: django, attachment, azure-data-lake

I have a Django application, I have written the API to handle files uploads with Django-Rest-framework. I have tested everything and it works with storing the attachments in my local laptop. 
However, I want the attachment to be store in a data lake, and I have tried to search what I should put in the settings, or what should be done so that instead of creating a local folder in our laptop and store the attachment, the attachment will be stored in the data lake. 
Does anyone have any experience with it?

Comment: You'll need to use a [custom file storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-file-storage/) class and use it as your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`. I don't know if someone has already written one for azure-data-lake. But using the azure python SDK you should be able to write one yourself.

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you know where can I find a more detailed instruction, because I have no experience with azure python sdk and I do not know how should I start

Comment: No I don't. Maybe look at [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/azure_storage.py) for an example on how they use the azure sdk to define a storage class. This is using the normal azure blob storage. Here's the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-datalake-store/azure.datalake.store.core.azuredlfilesystem?view=azure-python) for the data lake filesystem. Since it contains all the usual commands of `FileStorage`, it should be quite easy to write.